How to terminate Promt textarea in Laravel Pest Tests?
im using the new textarea promt in an artisan command.
To finish the input you have to press ^D (on Mac). In the test i'm using ->expectsQuestion(). The test is waiting for the promt to be terminated. How can i terminate the promt so the test can continue?

The answer to this problem is provided by Jess Archer in this Github issue https://github.com/laravel/prompts/issues/39

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
